# Replicate a table for each group in SQL Server, like R

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, dplyr, data.table

I am doing this operation in R;

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)


iris_groups <- iris %>% 
    select(Species) %>% 
    unique %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    group_split()

col_to_replicate <- mtcars %>% select(carb)

binder_fun <- function(x){
  cbind(x,col_to_replicate) %>% as.data.table
}

populated_data <- iris_groups %>% lapply(binder_fun) %>% rbindlist
```

As shown on the example, I want to duplicate a column (carb column of mtcars in this example) for each value in the left table (iris Species in this example)

A better explanation of ones who don't know R.

The first table is ;

```
|Species    |
|:----------|
|setosa     |
|versicolor |
|virginica  |
```

The second table is;

```
| carb|
|----:|
|    4|
|    4|
|    1|
|    1|
```

If I duplicate second table for each row in the first table it should look like ;

```
|Species    | carb|
|:----------|----:|
|setosa     |    4|
|setosa     |    4|
|setosa     |    1|
|setosa     |    1|
|versicolor |    4|
|versicolor |    4|
|versicolor |    1|
|versicolor |    1|
|virginica  |    4|
|virginica  |    4|
|virginica  |    1|
|virginica  |    1|
```

I am new to SQL and don't know how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would be far better off explaining your goal and providing sample data and expected results in a consumable format. The question itself doesn't have anything do with [[tag:r]]; yes you know how to do it in R, but R and SQL are *completely* different languages and are nothing alike.

Comment: I am looking for someone who knows R and SQL and understands what I am trying to say.  How do you suggest me to ask the question ? How can I achieve the solution in your opinion ? Instead of lecturing me, solution options will be better.

Comment: *"How do you suggest me to ask my question ?"* As I stated "You would be far better off explaining your goal and providing sample data and expected results in a consumable format."

Comment: Alternatively, have a read of [How should we tag code translation questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/how-should-we-tag-code-translation-questions). Effectively, here, you are asking how to translate the above from R to T-SQL; you don't explain where you got stuck, what you've tried, nor what you don't understand. If you haven't got any SQL, that's fine, but you need to accuracy explain your problem so that does that can't read R can still answer.

Comment: Ok, I added some clear explanations. Can you check it out and share your comments again ?

Comment: What you are after is a `CROSS JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness and because the question is tagged `data.table`: The `data.table` package has a convenient *cross join* function `CJ()`.

```
data.table::CJ(Species = unique(iris$Species), carb = head(mtcars$carb, 4L))
```

> ```
>        Species  carb
>  1:     setosa     1
>  2:     setosa     1
>  3:     setosa     4
>  4:     setosa     4
>  5: versicolor     1
>  6: versicolor     1
>  7: versicolor     4
>  8: versicolor     4
>  9:  virginica     1
> 10:  virginica     1
> 11:  virginica     4
> 12:  virginica     4
> ```

Note that we start right away with the original datasets `iris` and `mtcars`. All intermediate steps to extract a vector of unique `Species` as well as the first 4 elements of `carb` are included in the code above.

---

As the OP asked for  the equivalent SQL statement:

```
sqldf::sqldf("
SELECT Species, carb FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Species FROM iris)
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT carb FROM mtcars LIMIT 4)
")
```

which returns the same result.

Again, we have started right away with the original datasets and use 2 subqueries for the intermediate steps.

Note that the LIMIT clause depends on the SQL dialect.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest looking into the package `dbplyr` as it is meant to help do this translation. If you're connecting to the database with R, you don't even necessarily need to see the SQL. There's also the `show_query()` that will print the SQL. That being said it mainly translates tidyverse so you would actually need to change your R to get it to work.

As @Lamu mentioned, you are looking for a `CROSS JOIN`. R does some automatic replication under the hood when your columns are different lengths, but SQL you have to be more explicit. Assuming you have the tables created in the database already:

```sql
SELECT Species FROM iris
CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT carbs FROM mtcars
)
```

Depending on which SQL database or query engine you are using, there can be slightly different dialects of SQL. It might also be referred to as a `CARTESIAN JOIN`. Realize for a large table, this can be a very time intensive operation. In SQL you can also use constants in the query. As a result, you could test if this is the correct syntax with this query which should give you back the example result from above

```sql
SELECT  
    *
FROM (
    VALUES
        ('setosa'),
        ('versicolor'),
        ('virginica')
) AS iris (Species)
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  
    *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            (4),
            (4),
            (1),
            (1)
    ) AS mtcars (carbs)
) 
ORDER BY Species
```